# all but one sub-strings within a cyclic string

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

over $GF(q)$ where $q\in\mathbb{N}$, we build a string of size $q^n-1$. now, how can I show that it is always possible to construct that string so it contains all sub-strings of size $n$ exactly once, but the one sub-string missing is $x^n$ for some $x\in GF(q)$?

Comment: what is q? and what is the string?

Comment: It is always possible to build one. For example with $q=n=2$ you can get "001", it avoids "11" but it has "00" "01" and "10".

Comment: the question is how to prove that it is always possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $q=p^n$  a prime power let $\rho$ be a generator of $\mathbb{F}_q^{\ast}$. Let $X^n+c_{n-1}X^{n-1}+\ldots+c_0 \in \mathbb{F}_p[X]$ be the minimum polynomial of $\rho$. Now define a sequence as follows. $$x_0, x_2, \ldots, x_{n-1} = 0, 0, \ldots, 1$$ and for $m \geq n$ $$x_m = -c_{n-1}x_{m-1}-c_{n-2}x_{m-2}-\ldots-c_0x_{m-n}.$$ This will result in a sequence of period $q-1$ that contains all strings of length $n$ as a substring except $0^n$.

Here's an example for $q=2^4$. A root of $X^4+X+1$ happens to generate $\mathbb{F}_{16}^{\ast}$. This leads to the recursion $x_m=x_{m-3}+x_{m-4}$ in $\mathbb{F}_2$. Starting with $0,0,0,1$ this results in $$0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1, \ldots$$ which indeed contains all possible strings of length $4$ except $0,0,0,0$.

Another example for $q=3^2$. Now a root of $X^2+2X+2$ generates $\mathbb{F}_9^{\ast}$ so use the recursion $x_m=x_{m-1}+x_{m-2}$ to get $$0,1,1,2,0,2,2,1,0,1,\ldots$$ which again contains all possible strings of length $2$ except $0,0$.

Comment: what about q that is not a prime power?